# Finding Data in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Hello is there anyway that I can search my Excel Document in a certain column for an existing data?, and if the data does exist can I have my code execute something different. I have looked into it quite a bit and found nothing of great use. This was one of the site I have checked out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a(v=vs.80).aspx. I found this below, but don't know if there is a way I can use this as an if statement. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
currentFind = this.Fruits.Find("apples", missing,
Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
missing, missing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
if (currentFind == null)
{
// Do this if nothing found...
}
else
{
// Do this if something found...
}
```

Comment: That is actually pretty interesting actually that may work. Thanks I am going to give that a try